# Simple way to graph Wordpress publish dates?

Tags: php, wordpress, date, graph, publish

this is my first question on Stack Overflow and I'm non-programmer trying to pick it up. (Familiar with HTML, CSS, starting to get into a bit of PHP, did some tutorials on JavaScript and Ruby on Rails but forgot most of that stuff.)

I'm currently doing a writing project, where I'm writing 1,000 blogposts of 1,000 words each, published to a Wordpress blog, hosted on BlueHost. I'm up to about 315 posts published, which means 315,000++ words and 315 publishing dates. When I finish the project, it will be over 1,000,000 words and 1,000 published posts. (With about another 100 "summary" posts, and probably a 100 more "common threads" or "themes" posts.)

I'm hoping to use this project to as motivation teach myself some programming. For example, I want to print a graph of all the publish dates of my blogposts, so I can see at a glance what my publishing frequency is like.

For the time being, I'll be happy just to be able to look at a graph that was generated by anything other than my own manual labor. The easier, the better.

Comment: I am afraid this requires a lot of custom coding and after searching for a while I found just one plugin that is premium and I don't even know that match your requirement! https://www.cminds.com/store/purchase-cm-custom-reports-plugin-for-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Well its not that difficult to make a graph out of all your posts. But it needs a bit of understanding of the javascript. But i guess you just need some funky looking stuff on your website :). So here are my recommendations.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/blog-stats-by-w3counter/screenshots/
It can show you different graphs and statistics of your website. like how many people viewed your posts, which posts are doing good, which keywords they used to get to the website etc. I haven't tried it but it can might also have a timeline of all the posts that you had made.

Not a graph but if you want to show the posts in a calendar you can try this 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/editorial-calendar/

**EDIT: Well as you are looking into learning and are not afraid of getting your hands dirty, here is what you have to do to achieve this.**

1) First you have to get all the posts in the page that you want to show your graph on. The code below will list the title and date of all your publish posts.

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1,'post_type' => 'post','post_status'      => 'publish' );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    echo 'Title: '.the_title();
    echo 'Date: '.the_date().'<br/>';
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

2) You will have to learn some basics of javascript. I recommend you subscribe to teamtreehouse.com as they offer some of the best tutorials for beginers. Once you are comfortable with js you will then have to start looking at google graph's api. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/) for that.

**OR** 
if google chart is a bit too much for you, you can also try a wordpress plugin called ["WORDPRESS CHARTS"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-charts). Once the plugin is installed there are some shortcodes available to use. In your case you can just use this shortcode and replace the data set with the post date and labels with the title title of the posts.

```
[wp_charts title="Post Stats" type="line" align="alignright" margin="5px 20px" datasets="40,43,61,50 next 33,15,40,22" labels="one,two,three,four"]
```